# Mavericks Python 3.4 pip install error

Tags: python, macos, pip

Trying to install pip and I get this error
following https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

```
Sumners-MacBook-Pro:Downloads Sumner$ python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Downloading pip-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/req.py", line 1380, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/req.py", line 664, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/req.py", line 894, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 202, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/l6/0vw_83pn3kq52x2wjhkmns2r0000gn/T/tmpAovvNy/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 189, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Sumner/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: From looking at this error: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` it may be the case that you need to run this command as another user _(perhaps a [user that has higher permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277716/permission-denied-error-when-trying-to-install-pip-in-mac-os-x-lion?rq=1) than your current user?)_

Comment: actually I figured it out >.< pip3 no longer pip

Answer (score 8):

As I cannot comment due to my lack of 50 reputation, I will 'comment' in an answer.

Although you may be admin, you still have to type `sudo` before you do anything...
To check if your account has admin privileges, type `sudo bash` in your terminal, and if it says `myusername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`, then you aren't an admin.

Here is a short demonstration of the above:

```
ajs-iMac-5:~ aj8uppal$ sudo bash
Password:
bash-3.2# 
bash-3.2# exit
ajs-iMac-5:~ aj8uppal$ pip install colorama
Downloading/unpacking colorama
  Downloading colorama-0.2.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip_build_aj8uppal/colorama/setup.py) egg_info for package colorama

Installing collected packages: colorama
  Running setup.py install for colorama
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/colorama': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip_build_aj8uppal/colorama/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip-geh1_f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

creating build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/__init__.py -> build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/ansi.py -> build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/ansitowin32.py -> build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/initialise.py -> build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/win32.py -> build/lib/colorama

copying colorama/winterm.py -> build/lib/colorama

running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/colorama
```

> **THE ERROR:** error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/colorama': Permission denied

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip_build_aj8uppal/colorama/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip-geh1_f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/pip_build_aj8uppal/colorama
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/f7/r3hxg4tx3859tjpb0n_q9hnw0000gp/T/tmptJWePV
ajs-iMac-5:~ aj8uppal$ sudo pip install colorama
Downloading/unpacking colorama
  Downloading colorama-0.2.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/colorama/setup.py) egg_info for package colorama

Installing collected packages: colorama
  Running setup.py install for colorama

Successfully installed colorama
Cleaning up...
ajs-iMac-5:~ aj8uppal$
```

Or you could combine the first two steps and head into the third one, and if it raises an error when you type in `sudo`, then you aren't an admin.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go! You need admin privilege to do it. Type `sudo python get-pip.py` and enter the admin password.

It will automatically install pip-6.1.1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because the default version of Python, shipped with the OSX operating system, requires sudo permissions to run in a few places.

In general you probably shouldn't be developing with the operating system version of python, and I personally prefer never to sudo install anything that doesn't obviously need root access.

Instead of using the default version, install a user-specific Python installation with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
brew install python
```

And then you get the `pip` command properly installed for free!